How can I exclude application dependencies from search results in IntelliJ-idea when looking for a class or file on a Flutter Project?
Im using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.3 (Community Edition) and I want to search only over my project files and not its dependencies classes.
For example, when I search for files or classes for "build" I see all of the ios/.symlinks/*
Searching on files it shows a lot of classes that are not mine

Searching for classes it shows a lot of classes that are not mine


To exclude a folder

Show hidden files, search with cmd+shift+a and Show hidden files:


Search the folder, click it and then cmd+shift+a and put Excluded:



To exclude all files with *.g.dart

